# Which way of converting int[] to Integer[] is fastest?

Tags: java, arrays, performance

I am trying to convert a very long `int[]` with length of 1,000,000 to `Integer[]` so that I can sort it with a custom comparator (which sorts elements based on the length of their corresponding lists in a defined `Map<Integer, List<Integer>>`).

I have done the following:

```
private static Integer[] convert(int[] arr) {
        Integer[] ans = new Integer[arr.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            ans[i] = arr[i];
        }
        return ans;
    }
```

It works well for me but I have also come across

```
Integer[] ans = Arrays.stream(intArray).boxed().toArray( Integer[]::new );
```

and

```
Integer[] ans = IntStream.of(intArray).boxed().toArray( Integer[]::new );
```

Is there any of them that is significantly faster than the rest? Or is there any other approach that is fast enough to shorten the run-time?

Comment: Are you certain that the solution you have doesn't already yield adequate performance?

Comment: Premature Optimization. You won't see any difference unless your arrays are millions of elements, and even then figuring out which is marginally faster is a major project due to JIT optimization.  Don't worry about it unless you can prove there's a bottleneck.

Comment: Well, why do you need an `Integer[]`? You could just write a comparator for the `int` type.

Comment: Is it really necessary to have an `Integer[]`? How does your comparator look like? It probably will unbox all the `Integer`s to `int`s anyway when applying arithmetic operators

Comment: "Is there any of them that is significantly faster than the rest?" Did you try running the code to see how long it takes?

Comment: Please note that the `time-complexity` tag is not for all questions about how long it takes to run the code. It is for questions related to *how the time taken by an algorithm relates to the problem size*. Doing something to each element of an array is going to be O(n) no matter what  "something" is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there any of them that is significantly faster than the rest?

You realize the question you're asking is akin to:

"I have 500,000 screws to screw into place. Unfortunately, I can't be bothered to go out and buy a screwdriver. I do have a clawhammer and an old shoe. Should I use the clawhammer to bash these things into place, or is the shoe a better option?"

The answer is clearly: Uh, neither. Go get a screwdriver, please.

To put it differently, if the 'cost' of converting to `Integer[]` first is 1000 points of cost in some arbitrary unit, then the difference in the options you listed is probably between 0.01 and 0.05 points - i.e. dwarfed so much, it's irrelevant. Thus, the direct answer to your question? It just does not matter.

You have 2 options:

1. Performance is completely irrelevant. In which case this is fine, and there's absolutely no point to actually answering this question.
2. You care about performance quite a bit. In which case, this `Integer[]` plan needs to be off the table.

Assuming you might be intrigued by option 2, you have various options.

The easiest one is to enjoy the extensive java ecosystem. Someone's been here before and made an excellent class *just* for this purpose. It abstracts the concept of an int array and gives you all sorts of useful methods, including sorting, and the team that made it is extremely concerned about performance, so they put in the many, many, many personweeks it takes to do proper performance analysis (between hotspot, pipelining CPUs, and today's complex OSes, it's **much** harder than you might think!).

Thus, I present you: [IntArrayList](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/11.0.0/org/eclipse/collections/impl/list/mutable/primitive/IntArrayList.html). It has a `.sortThis()` method, as well as a `.sortThis(IntComparator c)` method, which you can use for sorting purposes.

There are a few others out there, searching the web for 'java primitive collections' should find them all, if for some reason the excellent eclipse collections project isn't to your liking (NB: You don't need eclipse-the-IDE to use it. It's a general purpose library that so happens to be maintained by the eclipse team).

If you must handroll it, searching the web for how to implement quicksort in java is not hard, thus, you can easily write your own 'sort this int array for me' code. Not that I would reinvent that particular wheel. Just pointing out that it's not too difficult if you must.